# What can you do with an Arduino using no extra components?

Tags: arduino

What projects can be made with an Arduino using a minimum of extra components save what can be found around the house?

Answer (score 6):

A wide variety of toys and electronics operate on TTL.  For example, you could take an Radio controlled toy car or microav and control it via an Arduino.

Comment: Here's a tutorial http://www.glacialwanderer.com/hobbyrobotics/?p=7

Answer (score 3):

Using a speaker taken from an old pair of headphones, make [R.I.F.F](http://tn42.com/riff) The Randomly Influenced Finger Flute.

You touch floating inputs to trigger a music generator.

Answer (score 3):

If you felt like a challenge, you could try and display different types of data with only the on-board LED. Someone out there made a single-LED voltmeter.

If you had an old alarm clock laying around with an LED display, there's a lot of blinky fun. Carefully extract out the LED display, look for a model number and get the data sheet; or probe the pins with 2V to learn how to light up each segment. Plus there would be a buzzer or speaker you could make use of as others have mentioned

With a light-dependent resistor and a speaker or piezo you could make one of those hand-held things that made noise when waved around on an alien surface in the original Star Trek show

If you had a model train set, using a few cheap relays and some resistors you could computer-control track sections just like a real railway

[Appliance](http://www.practicalarduino.com/projects/appliance-remote-control) remote control could be done for under US$20

[self-promo] if you were willing to spend US$25 or so you could follow the first five chapters of my [Arduino tutorials](http://tronixstuff.com/tutorials).